# How to find the eigenvectors within a specific eigenvalue range for a large sparse symmetric matrix (162000 by 162000)?

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I would like to find all the eigenvectors within a specific eigenvalue range. The matrix i am dealing with is large sparse symmetric matrix with size `(162000, 162000)`. I am using

```
Eigenvalue, Eigenvector = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=10, sigma="""105 to 205""")
```

I cannot use `sigma = 105 to 205`, i have written just for understanding my purpose.

Question 1: I want all the eigenvectors in the eigenvalue range of `sigma = 105 to 205`. How can I do this in `python`?

Question 2: Is it possible to calculate all the eigenvalue and eigenvectors for this large matrix in `python`?

The application is specific to structural dynamics where the stiffness and mass matrix is of the same size `(162000, 162000)`.

Comment: You have probably played with the `sigma` and `mode` parameters more than most of us.  Can you get useful results for a single `sigma` value (as opposed to a range)?

Comment: You mean i should extract one eigenvalue and one eigenvector at a time. I can get results for single sigma using eigsh.

Comment: I haven't used this feature enough to be sure, but it does look like it handles one value (or neighborhood), but not a range.